# div size doesn't equal top and bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code I've found that the `div` size doesn't equal at the top and bottom of the `ul`.

The `div` still doesn't have equal size even though I put the padding equal.
What is wrong?

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #4dbce9;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.footer ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer a {
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rony.fhebrian" />Facebook
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ronyfhebrian" />Twitter
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://ronyfhebrian.wordpress.com" />Blog
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="mailto:rony.fhebrian@outlook.com">Contact
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<a>` closing tag is missing.

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #4dbce9;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.footer ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer a {
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-8">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rony.fhebrian">Facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ronyfhebrian">Twitter</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="https://ronyfhebrian.wordpress.com">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="mailto:rony.fhebrian@outlook.com">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ul element should look like this :

```html
<ul>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rony.fhebrian">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ronyfhebrian">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="https://ronyfhebrian.wordpress.com">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="mailto:rony.fhebrian@outlook.com">Contact</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

the 'a' link tag is not self closing

Answer (score 0):

try to close the `<a>`tags ..

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/rony.fhebrian" />Facebook</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.twitter.com/ronyfhebrian" />Twitter</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://ronyfhebrian.wordpress.com" />Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="mailto:rony.fhebrian@outlook.com">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```